# ProGuard reducing APK size only 1MB out of 35MB

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, proguard

I am using Xamarin.Forms. I have Android app of size 35MB after applying **`ProGuard`** it only reduce nearly 1MB of size.  I have checked `ProGuard` option in Property window and added custom `proguard.cfg` file in my android project level to remove warnings.

Linker using 'SDK and User assemblies'.

proguard.cfg file

```
-dontwarn com.symbol.emdk.**
-dontwarn com.symbol.emdk.scanandpair.**
-dontwarn com.symbol.emdk.simulscan.**
-dontwarn com.symbol.emdk.barcode.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.**
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout { *; }
```

Is there any way to reduce APK size more using ProGuard only?

Comment: Is it in native or xamarin?

Comment: This is Xamarin.Forms

Comment: This link might help you https://montemagno.com/how-to-keep-your-android-app-size-down/

Comment: ProGuard won't optimize Xamarin part of your app. 35 MB is quite normal size of Xamarin app.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko - Then why 1MB getting reduced?

Comment: because of `Android`'s part of app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you develop a Xamarin application there is not much use in using ProGuard as most of the code will be compiled as native code and included as dll in the final apk.

ProGuard processes only JVM class files (there are different languages that produce class files, e.g. java, kotlin, groovy, ...).

Answer (score -1):

These 4 things reduce your apk size almost 50-60%

Replace **proguard-android.txt** with **proguard-android-optimize.txt**.

Make **minifyEnabled true**

Add **shrinkResources true**

Add **resConfigs**

ex:-

```
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    resConfigs "en"
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

}

Details:

proguard-android-optimize.txt is the more aggressive progurard configuration than proguard-android.txt.

shrinkResources attribute will remove all the resources, those are not used anywhere in the project.

resConfigs attribute will remove all the other localized resources while building the application. Here, it strips other than english resources.

Comment: Kuldeep, This is Xamarin application. Pl check tags. Thank you.

Comment: sorry i have missed that.